How to pass a positional argument from one function to *args in another function in python
I have a two scripts and a custom email module with two Functions that works.
But I need a single generic function in the custom email module used by both the scripts .
Script 1
import email_module.email import send_email
Some code here
File_count = sum([len(files) for r, d, files in os.walk(input_file)])
File_size_in_bytes= code here to get the File size in bytes
File_size = code here to get the File size in gb/mb
If a condition fails the scripts would trigger an email
Else
Send_email( a,b,c ,file_count,file_size_in_bytes)
Else
Send_email(a b,c,file_count, file_size)
Script2:
Some code here
Send_email_rfb(a,b,c,url,msg)
Email_module
def send_email(a,b,c,fcnt,fsize)
fc = str(fcnt)
fs= str(fsize)
Subject="alert on {a} "
Text=f'discrepency the filecount is {fc} and filesize is {fs}
def send_email_rfb (a,b,c,weburl,error_msg)
Subject= "alert on {a}
Text= (weburl, error_msg)
All this works perfectly . As there are two separate email functions for two scripts .
Facing issue when I try to create a generic single function
Since positional arguments  a,b,c are same .I was asked to create a single generic function
def send_email(a,b,c,*args)
Here I am stuck not sure how to get the values of file_count to fc and file_size_in_bytes, file_size to fs

In Python *args will return tuple of provided arguments to the function. You can simply access them by getting them by index.
In your case your function:
def Send_email(a, b, c , file_count, file_size_in_bytes):
    ...

Can be written as:
def Send_email(a, b, c, *args):
    file_count = args[0]
    file_size_in_bytes = args[1]


From what I understand, you want one function send_email(a,b,c, *args) where the args can be file_count, file_size and file_size in bytes for script1 and fcnt, fsize if used in script2.
For your combined send_email function, it can be defined in this way:
def send_email(a, b, c, *args, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('file_count') and (kwargs.get('file_size') or kwargs.get('file_size_in_bytes')):
        # code for the send_email used in script 1
    if kwags.get('fcnt') and kwargs.get('fsize'):
        # Code for send_email used in script 2
    # You can add a case for missing arguments and raise exception or log error for it.

